# "Practical" use of time-continuous stochastic processes like Wiener process or Poisson (point) process?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If one uses the Wiener process as an ingredient to model something, then for practical purposes one could just as well take a simple discrete random walk (with sufficiently fine scale).
If one uses a homogenous Poisson point process, one could just as well partition space and/or time into equal cells and take a sequence of independent 0-1 random variables describing whether the cells are occupied or empty.

"Practical" questions never force you to use the continuum. Similarly, instead of using integrals one could always use finite sums. However, sometimes there is a very simple expression for an integral, but not for the corresponding sum, for the solution of a differential equation, but not for the difference equation, or certain manipulations may be easier in the continuous than in the discrete case. In this sense, the continuum also has a purely practical use.

My question is: What would be the simplest examples for "practical" applications of Wiener process and Poisson (point) processes and practical advantages over the discrete analogues?
Putting it slightly differently: If one is not interested in the continuum for fundamental reasons or as something that has its value in itself, what can be reasons to study these processes?

---

@ Thomas Kojar and also others:

OK, one can reduce everything to a few continuous models, but one could also replace each of these by a computationally particularly convenient discrete model - because "details do not matter" anyway. I am looking for "practical" examples where it is better not to do the last step.

In case of the corresponding analysis question "Why not always use  sums instead of integrals?", a simple example would be $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ and $\int_l^u x^p\text dx$ and an everyday application of this would be to compute positions from accelerations. Some examples like this would satisfy me. Stochastic processes are a more advanced topic, so the simplest possible answers might be more complicated than this, but I am looking, as far as possible, for simple, maybe unspectacular examples where all details can be checked with a reasonable amount of effort and some general mathematical knowledge. Can you come up with something like this? "Studying PDE via Feynman-Kac formula" does not satisfy this...

And maybe, since I wrote it in the title but then maybe obscured it in the text, I should empasize: I am particularly wondering about discrete vs. continuous time. I am not worried whether to use a random walk with +/- 1 steps or with Gaussian steps, but about situations when it is good to add an evolution for all rational (or real, but that will hardly matter) times to the Gaussian random walk.

Comment: No-arbitrage pricing arguments for option pricing very specifically rely on continuous time formulations. They require that you dynamically hedge a contract continuously - such hedging arguments can't be used in discrete time.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Sorry, but I'm not sure that that's entirely correct.  There definitely exist discrete time financial models that price using no-arbitrage arguments and hedging, e.g. the binomial model.  These are analogous to the random walk idea mentioned in the question in that they do approach the continuous time solutions when the scale is sufficiently fine.

Comment: @user6247850 sure - agreed, but in those models there are only finitely many possible prices at each timestep. In the case of continuous prices we need continuous hedging.

Comment: For the updated question: It depends who you talk to. To speak more on the KPZ universality. There are people from many different fields eg. exciton-photon polariton, who have their own discrete models that they are interested to study and that happen to somewhat relate to KPZ.

Comment: They are not necessarily interested in studying other discrete models from other areas where KPZ showed up even if they are more computationally better eg. mRNA protein synthesis model, forest-fires and coffee percolation. But all of these people are interested to get nice formulas for KPZ that they can try to relate to their particular models (eg. via obtaining convergence rates).

Comment: But of course, if one can get a nice discrete model such as random-walk for Brownian motion or TASEP/WASEP for KPZ universality (which by the way was used to proved new properties for the KPZ fixed point), then researchers use them all the time. One should jump between the discrete and the continuum perspective as  much as possible to get more information for the overall situation.

Comment: @rubikscube09,user6247850 : OK, so the situation with Black-Scholes is roughly: One can do it in discrete time with finitely many prices. Using continuous stock prices has the advantage that their distribution does not become more complicated as time proceeds. So, looking only at the stock price, a geometric brownian motion in discrete time would look quite practical. Do I understand you correctly that with time-discretized geometric brownian motion the arguments to find the fair option price do not work?

Comment: Comment continued: If so, this is nice and I have to check the details. The question remains: Is there a more minimal example of this kind?

Comment: @ Thomas Kojar: "One should jump between the discrete and the continuum perspective as much as possible to get more information for the overall situation." Fine - here I have the same question: Do you have some precise "minimal example" where this jumping is essential? A clean mathematical example that can be understood without much background, particular physical models, ..., just a simple question about Brownian motion and random walks or the like?

Answer (score 9):

You answered your own question, I think. Many physics/economics models involve partial differential equations which often are studied using Feynman-Kac (among many other methods), which involves Brownian motion.

These have exact formulas compared to the finite-difference relations. So they are much easier to study and draw conclusions from compared to finite-difference relations. For example, in Durrett, I remember he proved a Random-Walk Laws of the Iterated Logarithm using the continuous one via the Skorokhod-embedding.

Another major reason is Universality (eg. KPZ universality). Here the discrete-interactions and specificities get averaged out. This is a general principle of physics saying that the discrete-details often don't matter, so we might as well reduce to studying only a few continuous models that are "Fixed Points" for many discrete models.

Answer (score 4):

I could add a couple things to the already existing good answers.

1. Continuous time processes are not that bad/that much more difficult to define or to simulate numerically in practice. For a Markov chain in a discrete or even finite state space, going from discrete time to continuous time amounts to making the time intervals between when something happens random, e.g., exponentially distributed instead of fixed equal to some given time increment $\Delta t$.
   Moreover, some properties work nicely for this continuous time version but not so much for the discrete time version. See for example the correspondence with local times, related to the [Ray-Knight theorem(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_(mathematics)) or the Symanzik-Brydges-Fröhlich-Spencer-Dynkin isomorphisms. A good pedagogical review on this topic is ["The geometry of random walk isomorphism theorems"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01532) by Bauerschmidt, Helmuth and Swan.
2. Although constructing the continuum random object requires some work, e.g., rigorously getting Brownian motion $B_t$ as a limit of (discrete time and space) simple random walk.
   This effort pays off in having beautiful exact symmetries properties hold for the continuum object. My favorite is the time inversion, i.e., equality in distribution
   of $tB_{1/t}$ with $B_t$. Good luck formulating that as a property of the simple random walk.

I like this example because this is the simplest instance of conformal invariance which is an important area in mathematical physics related to the work of W. Werner, S. Smirnov, M. Hairer, H. Duminil-Copin and many others.

Answer (score 1):

> As one example, the geometric Brownian motion is used in mathematical finance to model the price of the underlying asset, whence one derives the [Black–Scholes formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation#Solving_the_Black%E2%80%93Scholes_PDE) for the price of the corresponding European call/put options.

---

Quoted below is part of a response by ChatGPT (quite impressive, in my view) -- which I have read, understood, and approved. I have also added a detail at the end of the following quote:

> Poisson point process: A simple example of a Poisson point process is
> the modeling of customer arrival times in a queuing system, such as
> customers arriving at a bank or a call center. The Poisson point
> process is often used to model the arrival process because it captures
> the randomness and independence of customer arrival times. Advantages
> over discrete analogues:
>
> Simplicity: The Poisson process has very simple and intuitive
> properties, such as a constant arrival rate, which makes it easy to
> analyze and understand.
>
> Analytical tractability: Many queuing models
> based on the Poisson process have closed-form solutions or can be
> analyzed using well-established techniques, such as Markov chains or
> the Poisson equation. This is often more difficult for discrete-time
> models, especially when arrival rates vary over time.
>
> Time-scale
> invariance: The Poisson process is time-scale invariant, meaning that
> the statistical properties of the process do not change if the time
> scale is changed. This makes it suitable for modeling systems with
> various time scales, whereas discrete models may need to be adjusted
> for different time scales. [Added by me: Indeed, with the continuous-time Poisson point process, any variable arrival rate can be obtained from the constant rate by a simple, deterministic time change.]

Comment: Why the downvote? Is anything wrong in this answer?

Comment: Some people might be offended by the very thought of an AI being able to answer Mathoverflow questions. If only there was someone (or some_thing_) to discuss this with...

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky : Thank you for your comment. I did have a similar suspicion. And yes, it would be great to have a serious discussion on what mathematicians can/should do with and about AI tools.

Comment: Another anonymous downvote ...

Comment: Interesting: Two upvotes before I added the ChatGPT response, and two downvotes after that. I think the ChatGPT response was factually correct, detailed, and reasoned -- am I thoroughly wrong?

Comment: Thank you for another upvote!

Comment: And for yet another one!

Comment: -1 for the ChatGPT response, which (as is often the case with ChatGPT) sounds nice but is subtly incoherent. For example, it lists the constant arrival rate of the Poisson process as an advantage over discrete time analogs (is it?) but also claims the Poisson process is better equipped to deal with arrival rates that change over time.

Comment: @N.Virgo : Thank you for your comment -- at least now we can have a discussion. (i) You said "(as is often the case with ChatGPT) [it] sounds nice but is subtly incoherent." Do you really think that ChatGPT's incoherence rate is greater than that of an average MO user -- especially when its response was approved by a regular MO user? (ii) ChatGPT did not say that "the constant arrival rate of the Poisson process [is by itself] an advantage over discrete time analogs".

Comment: Previous comment continued: Rather, it said "[the constant arrival rate] makes it suitable for modeling systems with various time scales, whereas discrete models may need to be adjusted for different time scales." I understood this as follows: with the continuous-time Poisson point process, any variable arrival rate can be obtained from the constant rate by a simple, deterministic time change -- I have now added this detail. So, in light of this, would you be willing to reconsider your vote?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Thank you for your comment. The policy says "Use of ChatGPT generated text for content on Stack Overflow is temporarily banned." However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20is%20a%20question,of%20the%20Stack%20Exchange%20Network.) says "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network." So, Stack Overflow is only a certain part of the Stack Exchange Network. So, the mentioned policy does not seem to concern MathOverflow, or does it?

Comment: Here is the [link to the policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) referred to in Carlo Beenakker's comment (now deleted but still possibly relevant).

Comment: there is no unique network-wide policy (yet); an overview of the policies on different sites is at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384922/is-there-a-list-of-chatgpt-discussions-and-policies-for-our-sites ; reading through them, I do see a sort of consensus appearing, which is that we expect humans to answer questions here.

Comment: Wow. That ChatGPT answer is quite impressive. What was the precise question used to generate it?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : Thank you for your comment. The question was the same as the one in the OP, edited somewhat by me. I too am impressed by this response from ChatGPT. I would not use AI for MO purposes where I do not understand the subject matter well enough.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Thank you for your further comment. Concerning MO, I see there [only one link](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5531/chatgpt-strikes-mathoverflow), which concerns a situation clearly very different from the present case.

Comment: @RobertFurber : Wow! Let me try to understand your comment. It seems you are trying to say that either (i) I am "that stupid" or (ii) I do understand "what [a terrible thing] ChatGPT actually is" but use it nonetheless. Let's try not to talk about personalities or go into broad generalizations. In this specific case, do you see anything wrong with ChatGPT's response?

Comment: The bot answer, to my mind, is worth no further comment than that it is as bad as I would expect. Concerning your own answer, geometric brownian motion could well be replaced by $X_n=\prod_{k=1}^nY_k$ where $(Y_k)$ are nonnegative with expectation 1 and i. i. d. "Black-scholes" sounds promising, but it looks as if it could require considerable effort to figure out precisely what goes wrong with obvious starting points to try the same in discrete time. Can you reduce it somehow to a "minimal example"?

Comment: @MrH : (i) Of course, your "worth no further comment than that it is as bad as I would expect" warrants no response, except for: What specifically is bad in it? (ii) As for the discrete-time Black–Scholes, I think it does not exist (and I wonder what it could possibly be). You yourself may want to try to figure out what could go wrong with that -- say, by first trying to follow an existing proof of Black–Scholes. You may also want to try to ask that question on some question-and-answer forum, hoping someone would answer such a question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I mean "What ChatGPT is" in a very literal sense. As in how it works. So neither of your two options. I emphasize again that I have not downvoted you.

Comment: @RobertFurber : My question to you was not about what you meant by "What ChatGPT is". Mainly, it was the following: "In this specific case, do you see anything wrong with ChatGPT's response?" It was not quite clear to me what you meant in your first comment here. However, it seemed that you felt so strongly about my post and ChatGPT that you wanted to express your feelings in a certain rather unusual way, even at the risk of getting banned. Anyhow, I would prefer it if you just answer my question: "In this specific case, do you see anything wrong with ChatGPT's response?"

Comment: God says: I veto that I'm bored game changer bickering well I never watch it buddy little buddy I'm impressed hot air I'm in suspense lulz astrophysics one more time It grieves me cheerful kludge skills do it no way dude chump change ordinarily obviously eh is it just me or endeavor as a matter of fact ice cream energy recipe what's it to you astronomical What

Comment: @RobertFurber : Is your latest comment here the answer to my repeated question to you: "In this specific case, do you see anything wrong with ChatGPT's response?"? If so, this comment of yours is apparently too deep for me, and I should ponder it for quite some time.

Comment: @RobertFurber not really constructive pursuing this line of conversation, probably better to let it lie.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I appreciate the fact you didn't try to pass off a bot-generated response as your own work, and clearly marked it as such, but this feels to me like something that doesn't really result in a net-positive contribution. Anyone can go and get ChatGPT (or similar) to generate such an "answer", but is it worth copying it here and making it look like you endorse such an answer (whether you do or not)? Continuing to try to ask Robert to give you feedback is not helping either, as you can see.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Regarding [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443335/practical-use-of-time-continuous-stochastic-processes-like-wiener-process-or-p/443347#comment1144621_443347) "at least now we can have a discussion": don't forget that MO is not a discussion forum, and such a discussion is best held elsewhere.

Comment: Lastly, how would you feel about a student who answered an assignment question (or a mathematician who wrote a paper!) but instead of pretending it was their own work, it was an openly acknowledged cut-and-paste from a chat bot? Since MO doesn't want (at least currently, as there's no guarantee of correctness) chatGPT answers (or similar) passed off as user contributions, I don't see how merely being open about it qualitatively changes the value of such an answer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts : Your comment "I appreciate the fact you didn't try to pass off a bot-generated response as your own work" is offensive. Would you welcome any (let alone public) "appreciation" of the fact that you did not cheat on a certain occasion? Instead of that comment, you could have said nothing about this or, **at worst, just** something like "I appreciate it that you clearly marked it as such".

Comment: Previous comment continued: As for your comment "I don't see how merely being open about [using ChatGPT] qualitatively changes the value of such an answer", I do not see what this has to do with this case. Indeed, it is clear that, in addition to "merely being open" about the use of ChatGPT, I have read and understood its response; moreover, I approved it and was impressed by it (as was at least one other quite established MO user). That a question can be correctly answered by ChatGPT means, tautologically, that ChatGPT is a good tool for such a question.

Comment: Previous comment further continued: Perhaps then the problem is with the question (as possibly it is in the case with your hypothetical student). Finally, the quality of the answer is something anyone can see. I have asked repeatedly: "In this specific case, do you see anything wrong with ChatGPT's response?" I have not seen any valid answer to this question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm sorry I was offensive. People have literally tried to pretend ChatGPT output is their own writing here. By "appreciate" I don't mean I appreciate it, as in "thank you", I mean that I acknowledge that you did so, but that I don't think that this redeems the post more than someone who didn't flag the content as AI-generated. If the OP wanted an AI-generated answer, they could have asked ChatGPT. Had your answer come with commentary explaining this automatically-generated answer, why you think it correct and interesting, then this would add value based on your expertise.

Comment: _I have asked repeatedly: "In this specific case, do you see anything wrong with ChatGPT's response?" I have not seen any valid answer to this question._ <--- perhaps this should go in a new question, rather than try to drum up discussion in comments. Already the software is trying to push these comments into a private chat room. _That a question can be correctly answered by ChatGPT means, tautologically, that ChatGPT is a good tool for such a question._ <--- it tells us that this time, ChatGPT managed to not mess up. Asked the same question again, it might generate drivel, as it has before.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I think a discussion on meta is warranted about whether answers that consist largely of uncommented chatGPT (or similar) output will be considered as within what MO wants. We aren't going to be able to thrash it out here, and it shouldn't just be us two discussing it. A separate discussion could be raised on meta about the technical content of chatGPT's answer if you want to try to get detailed comments, to keep focus, and aside from the general policy discussion. Again, sorry for coming across as insulting!

Comment: @DavidRoberts : I agree that I should have said right away, within my answer, that I had read, understood, and approved this response by ChatGPT, and also edited it a bit. This is now done.

Comment: @MrPinelis: "What specifically is bad in it [the bot response]?" Does this seriously need an explanation? Well: Most of the "answer" does not relate to my question. The passage that might at first sight look most relevant is "analytical tractability" but it also is not: First, it consists of rather empty phrases and is not at all helpful if I want to know something precise. Second, "closed analytical solution" might mean integrals or series that can only be evaluated numerically and, doing so, give a similar practical result as if one started with a discrete model.